# Basic C Programming - How to solve "Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'integer1' is being used without being initialized."

Tags: c

I'm a newbie who is trying to compile a simple code. This is the code I'm trying to compile.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int integer1; 
    int integer2; 
    int sum; 

    printf("Enter first integer\n"); 
    scanf( "%d", integer1 ); 

    printf( "Enter second integer\n" ); 
    scanf( "%d", integer2 ); 

    sum = integer1 + integer2; 

    printf( "sum is %d\n", sum ); 
    return 0;  
}
```

I am using the Visual Studio 2017 as compiler and I get the error below.

> Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'integer1' is being used without being initialized.

Could you please help?

Comment: C++ != C; I guessed you were asking about C.

Comment: Check the `scanf` manual again. You're using it incorrectly...

Comment: @HelloWorld: The behaviour of both expressions is actually undefined in C and C++. And C is superior in many ways, for example the ability to type pun through a union.

Comment: @HelloWorld That's simply wrong.

Comment: @HelloWorld C++ is not C and more. Or are there VLA available in C++ now?

Comment: @Gerhardh: although VLA support is optional from C11.

Comment: that ampersand thing...:( thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler is being really rather friendly.

You need to pass a *pointer* to the variable to be set by `scanf`, and you should *always* check the return value of `scanf`:

```
if (scanf("%d", &integer1) == 1){
    // all read correctly; i.e. 1 variable set
} else {
    // don't attempt to read `integer1`
}
```